# geom_bar ggplot2 subtract two Values

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
g = ggplot(Values, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill=factor(Z))) + 
        geom_bar(width=0.8, stat = "identity", position="dodge") +  
        facet_grid(Z ~ ., scale = "free_y") +  
        labs(x="Anno", y = "Riserva Rivalutata") + 
        theme(legend.position ="none") + 
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2000, 2070, by = 5))

d = ggplot(Values, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill=factor(Z))) + 
        geom_bar(width=0.8, stat = "identity", position="dodge") 

p = subplot(g,d, nrows=2, shareX= T,which_layout = 1)
```

Hello,
I'm creating an object that when I click 2 objects Z, shows me above 2 distinct graphs, while below I would like to see the subtraction of the two.

Right now I can only see them distinct.
Can you help me to make a single chart but with only one bar given by the difference between the two data?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: A sample of your data structure would be helpful, use `dput(Values)` and paste the results

Comment: I'm on the X axis.
on the axis of the Y I have the amounts.
While the fill (Z) is the type

Comment: The simplest is to compute the difference between the two `Z` levels before the plot (see `tidyr::spread`). As said by @GGamba, it is hard to help more without a reproducible example.

Comment: I would like to create a chart where the choice of two data sources makes the difference between the two on the Y axis.

I wrote this: ggplot (Values-, aes (x = X, y = (Values $ Y [1] -Values $ Y [2])))

but this "(Values $ Y [1] -Values $ Y [2])" makes the difference to me for the first value of the X, but it is the same for all the others.

Where am I wrong?